# Objective C and NSURLConnection

Tags: objective-c, ios5

I am new to ObjC and was writing a simple CONSOLE app to just get data from web and parse or do something with with.  I am trying to use NSURLConnection but am having problem getting any data.  I used TCPDUMP to capture traffic and I see the request doesn't even get sent out thus I don't even get any result back in console.  I am not trying to create ios app just a simple Console app on mac.  Any help would be highly appreciated. ** I am using Xcode v4.2 with ARC on this project.

**main.m:**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "HTTPRequest.h"

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {  
    HTTPRequest *http = [[HTTPRequest alloc]init];
    [http doMagic ];
    }
  return 0;
}
```

**HTTPRequest.h:**

```
 #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
    @interface HTTPRequest :NSObject <NSURLConnectionDelegate> {
       NSMutableData *webData;
       NSURLConnection *conn;
    }

    -(void) doMagic;

    @end
```

**HTTPRequest.m:**

```
#import "HTTPRequest.h"
@implementation HTTPRequest
-(void) doMagic {
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"];
    NSMutableURLRequest *req = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:req
                                           delegate:self];
    if (conn) {
        webData = [NSMutableData data];
        NSLog(@"DEBUG:  %@", [webData length]);
        }

    }

    -(void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response{
        [webData setLength:0];
    }

    -(void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
        [webData appendData:data];
    }
    -(void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
        NSLog(@"Connection failed! Error - %@ %@",
        [error localizedDescription],
        [[error userInfo] objectForKey:NSURLErrorFailingURLStringErrorKey]);
    }

    -(void) connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *) connection {

    NSLog(@"Succeeded! Received %lu bytes of data",[webData length]);

    NSLog(@"DONE.  Received Bytes: %lu", [webData length]);
    NSString *theData = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:[webData mutableBytes] 
                                                length:[webData length] 
                                              encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    // -prints html received --
    NSLog(@"%@", theData);
    }
    @end
```

Comment: You might need to call `[conn fire];`

Comment: You need a run loop for `NSURLConnection` to work. GUI apps have a run loop set up by default, but that's not the case for command line tools. Have a look at `NSRunLoop`.

Comment: Thx omz.  I think you are on to something as I created exact same thing with iOS and it works perfectly fine but for some reason it doesn't work on console apps and I think you are right about NSRunLoop (from my initial googling).  I will have a look at NSRunLoop and report back.  Thx man.  Really appreciate your help.

Comment: Got it working ... HOORAH!! Since I am new here I can't post the answer for another 6 hours. NSRunLoop basically solved the problem.   Will post back my answer.  Thanks OMZ.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks OMZ.  NSRunLoop was the answer.  Found great article on it here:
http://coc24hours.blogspot.com/2012/01/using-nsrunloop-and-nsurlconnection.html

And for the fix:

Just added this for testing only and it worked perfectly fine within the if statement:

```
  if (conn) {
        webData = [NSMutableData data];
        NSRunLoop *loop = [NSRunLoop currentRunLoop];
        [loop run]; 
        NSLog(@"DEBUG:  %@", [webData length]);
    }
```

Thanks to everyone for their help.

Answer (score 0):

I usually use the `startImmediately` parameter for my connections (as in, using the `initWithRequest:delegate:startImmedately:` to `NSURLConnection`.)  Maybe try with that?  If not, you will probably need to explicitly call `start`.

Also, I'm not sure if this is related to your problem, but you aren't retaining `webData`.  (You're initializing it with an autoreleased pointer, which will can be released before any of the NSURLConnectionDelegate callbacks.)

Comment: Thanks Turix. I did try startImmediately and explicit call to start but that doesn't work :( Also I can't retain webData as I am using ARC.